# What is the Horde capital?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What city is the Horde analog of the Alliance's Stormwind City? Specifically, I want to know where I can buy PvP armor and everything else one expects in a faction capital.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Horde equivalent is **Orgrimmar**, the Orc capital. It contains portals to cataclysm areas, PvP vendors, as well as everything standard to one of the big cities (Auction House, banks, class and profession trainers, etc.)